# how to Install Azure storage SDK for Java

Tags: java, azure, ubuntu, sdk

I want to install Azure storage SDK for Java on Ubuntu, I searched for it , but most of the documents are for eclipse and not for manual installation o Ubuntu.

Anyone have any idea how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen the download instructions here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java?

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, you can access the [maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage/4.2.0) of Azure Storage SDK to add the dependency configuration for your project which using maven, gradle or others as build manager and using Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA as IDE.

If you just want to donwload the SDK jar file, you can click the link at the maven repository page and see the file in the list, please see the figures below.

[image]

[image]